# How to transfer file only when it changed in salt?

Tags: salt-stack

I am using the following way to provide bundled software project to salt minions:

```
proj-archive:
  cmd:
    - run
    - name: "/bin/tar -zxf /home/myhome/Proj.tgz -C {{ proj_dir }}"
    - require:
      - file:  /home/myhome/Proj.tgz
      - {{ proj_dir }}
  file:
    - managed
    - user: someone
    - group: someone
    - mode: '0600'
    - makedirs: True
    - name: /home/myhome/Proj.tgz
    - source: salt://Proj.tgz
```

As far as I can tell, it does the job, but these rules are always active, even when archive have not changed. This brings unnecessary delays in deployment. In a similar situation, for example, service restart with `watch` clause on a file, it is possible to restart when file changed. How to tell salt to copy file over network only when it changed? Is there any automatic way to do it?

The **`Proj.tgz`** in salt directory is a symlink to file location, if it matters.

The `archive.extracted` is not that useful, because it does not trigger when changes are inside files, no files added or removed in the archive.

Some relevant info https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/40484 , but I am unsure of resolution / workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace both states with [salt.states.archive](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.archive.html). It might look like this:

```
proj-archive:
    archive.extracted:
        - name: {{ proj_dir }}
        - source: salt://Proj.tgz
        - user: someone
        - group: someone
        - source_hash_update: True
```

The key feature here is `source_hash_update`. From the docs:

> Set this to `True` if archive should be extracted if source_hash has changed. This would extract regardless of the `if_missing` parameter.

I'm not sure whether or not the archive gets transferred on each `state.apply`. But I guess it will not.

Comment: Nice! However, this needs `source_hash` to work. So, should I maintain some hash file also?

Comment: Don't they calculate the hash on their own? Maybe together with the `keep` parameter to not drop the local archive?

Comment: I added `source_hash` and `skip_verify`. Seems like the only change is updating ownership now...

Comment: Also, salt hits `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/states/archive.py", line 87, in _update_checksum` when there is no `skip_verify`. Maybe, some bug in archive implementation.

Comment: Even with other combinations of flags, this solution does not work. State does not react to change in hash, archive does not react to changes inside files (only adding or removing file triggers state enforcement). If anything, check before you use the archive.extracted in many situations.

Comment: Indeed: overwrite - "Set this to True to force the archive to be extracted. This is useful for cases where the filenames/directories have not changed, but the content of the files have."